# console log chrome can not display any results (even simple program javascript program)?

Tags: javascript

I am studying javascript and meet this problem.

I wrote a very simple program like this in visual studio

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<script>
console.log("Hello world");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And trying to display it at console log, but it does not, as you can see at the picture.
[image: Picture about console log problem]

I do not understand why, because the program is very simple.
Could you please give me some ideas to solve this problem ? Should I change to another one for example opera or firefox ?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Your "main.js" file contains HTML. And it normally wouldn't be served by default when you go to the URL. Usually it will load "index.html"

Comment: Your code is HTML, put it in index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code to mine locally, it works if you directly open the .html file. This might be cause of live server.

Try to right-click the folder that contains the index.html (lesson_1 in your case) then open with vscode, then try to run live server again.

I think you right-click > open with vscode at HOC JavaScript folder, so live server plugin is looking for index.html IN that folder (not in its subdir)

EDIT: didn't realize your html code is written in .js file.... that should be your first step...

Answer (score 0):

I will answer as the comments have already said.

1. Move your html code to the index.html file
2. Change script tag to: `<script src="main.js"></script>`
3. Move `console.log("Hello world");` to main.js file